# Angular 12 read "content" from JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Hi i have problem with angular and typescript i need fetch get api from spring where return variable is Page but my json look like this:

```
"content": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": "TSHIRT",
        "model": "fajne pants",
        "mark": "ADIDAS",
        "sizes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "sizeName": "XL",
                "count": 10
            }
        ],
        "price": 100.0,
        "discount": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": null,
        "model": "nowe naje",
        "mark": "NIKE",
        "sizes": [],
        "price": 199.0,
        "discount": 0
    },
],
"pageable": {
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "unpaged": false,
    "paged": true
},
"last": true,
"totalPages": 1,
"totalElements": 4,
"size": 20,
"number": 0,
"sort": {
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true,
    "empty": true
},
"first": true,
"numberOfElements": 4,
"empty": false
```

}

this content destroy my code in angular because he can;t go here
this is my service:

```
 getAll(){
return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/items?page=0");
```

}

and this is my component.ts:

```
 pantService.getAll().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result)
  console.log(result.content)
});
```

I need to this result paste to my itemsList: Array

Comment: What is in your console log?

Comment: console: undefined

Comment: I don't find anything wrong here. Can you check if you are able to return data from back-end? Check your network log also in browser.

Comment: ok in console log i have now response from back-end but my array is in content and i can't paste this arrays to my itemList:Array[], if i paste //@ts-ignore and make this.itemList = result["content"] it's work but why i need this @ts-ignore ?

Comment: Assign your array right after console statement. I don't see assigning itemList array anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I install : npm i axios
and make

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/items?page=0").then(r =>{
      this.pantsList = r.data.content
    });
```